# Azure Stream Analytics reference input cannot read from Storage blob

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-stream-analytics, azure-analytics

We are trying to create a Storage reference input for Azure Stream Analytics job and all the configuration and the test goes well, however when we try to use it in a Query, we get the following messages in the portal UI: "While sampling data, no data was received from '1' partitions." and "No data was found for preview from 'refinput'. Make sure the input has recently received data and  the correct format of those events has been selected." It is a CSV file that we have uploaded in the storage account and it is static data that doesn't change. The blob is a valid CSV and can be downloaded and opened in Excel without problems.

Any ideas on what the issue can be?

Comment: We tried even with a simple CSV like this.
```ProductNumber,ProductName
aa01,Coca-Cola
aa02,Pepsi
aa03,Fanta
aa04,7Up
aa05,Aquafina```

If this file is uploaded to Blob storage, ASA shows the above messages. However, we can upload the same file as sample input in the Query view ini ASA and it works.

Comment: the first guess is maybe you did not specify the file name while setting the ref data input in your ASA job? for example {date}/{time}/filename.json

Comment: We actually did and this is why it is puzzling. As I mentioned, it is a static file and there are no `{date/{time}` components of the path. We tried `filename.csv` as well as `somefolder/filename.csv` - none of those worked

Comment: You mean you tested good in ASA query portal UI with uploading sample file,but no luck with official execution of job,am i right?

Comment: hi,any progress here?

Comment: I will test this in the next few days and let you know if it works as you suggest below. However I remember seeing completely different error when we configured it. Will post screenshots too

Comment: @toddysm Okey,take your time.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, I have to say blob storage reference inputs cannot be previewed which is stated in the ASA portal UI.

[image]

As we know, reference input should be used in JOIN with Stream Input,can't be used alone. So, I suppose the error you met occurs when you test stream input join reference input. I reproduce same issue as yours, please see:

[image]

Per my knowledge, Preview Data is for real-time input stream, it simulates the real execution of ASA job. So you have to make sure that the input has recently received any correct format (which is indicated by error message exactly). Surely, you could set time range to scale the appropriate scope as you want.

[image]

As for upload sample data, that's totally static sample which will not be affected by any time settings. Just static data for test!

Comment: Hi Jay. A bit of feedback for you: (1) in general punctuation marks should be followed by a space, to aid readability and to ensure that sentences will automatically line break automatically; (2) opening brackets to add an aside should be prefixed with a space for the same reason; (3) inline code formatting should be reserved for code and console IO, it is not a general highlighter; (4) there is no need to add "hope this is clear/helps" etc, it is redundant. Technical writing is an expectation here.

Comment: Note that in order to maintain a curated set of Q&A we need material authors to put some effort into their material, and to adhere to a reasonably common set of writing standards. We just don't have enough good editors to repair everything, and indeed, it should be remembered they are volunteers - for the most part they do not even get reputation points for their work.